# Best approach: Use ValuesManager or something else?

Tags: smartgwt

Just to be clear, this is not a defects related question.  I'm much more interested in the preferred approach to a specific business requirement.

Also, we are currently using the LGPL Edition of SmartGWT version 3.1.

The requirement we have is to be able to edit a customer info record (Name, Phone #, etc.) and that info form also needs to support basic CRUD around customer addresses; all on the same form.  And so far, we have that working with the following objects:

CustomerInfo - Canvas

..SubscriptionForm - DynamicForm - Subscription Datasource

....AddressCanvasItem - to host the AddressGrid in the form

......AddressGrid - ListGrid - Address Datasource

........AddressForm - invoked in AddressGrid as a RecordComponent - used in read-only and read-write mode

The way this works now is that the user brings up the page for the customer, it shows their subscription form, and on that subscription form is a grid which shows a record component for each address and each one of those has an Edit button.  The user clicks on Edit or Add Address and we pop-up a Smart Window, where the user can make changes, click Save or Cancel.

The changes from an edit are then submitted directly to the server and the changes are persisted using a services layer.  The user can also edit the CustomerInfo fields on the form that contains the addresses and save/cancel those changes separately.

And that's all working now.

Now what the users REALLY want, and I just didn't know how to get it working the first time around, is to have the RecordComponents show a DynamicForm for each address.  Then when they click Add, it would pop in a new row with the DynamicForm ready for editing.  They would be able to edit each address without needing to click Edit first.  In short, they do not want the pop-ups to be needed for editing.

Ideally then, when the user clicks Save or Cancel on the CustomerInfo form, it would apply to all of the addresses as well as the customer info form fields.

So, my question is this: what's the best way to achieve this?  A ValuesManager appears to maybe be the answer, but it's not clear to me that it can support this kind of use.  Or, does this kind of usage require a product beyond the LGPL edition?

And finally, is there a sample that shows how to do something like this?  I did have this fairly close to working at one point, but I didn't see how to get multiple forms that are backed by different datasources to submit at the same time.  That issue is what drove me to use the AddressForm in read-write mode in a pop-up in the first place.  It keeps the CRUD traffic atomic and got me around the issue for the time being.

Thank you!